# What's 'Mean item complexity'?

Tags: factor-analysis, psychometrics

EFA to the data collected from my friend. R `psych::fa`output as below:

```
 With factor correlations of 
     MR1   MR2  MR3   MR4
MR1 1.00  0.02 0.39  0.46
MR2 0.02  1.00 0.09 -0.05
MR3 0.39  0.09 1.00  0.12
MR4 0.46 -0.05 0.12  1.00

Mean item complexity =  1.2
Test of the hypothesis that 4 factors are sufficient.
```

I read the help file of `complexity`,but what's the meaning of `Mean item complexity`?

Answer (score 3):

Reading the help file for fa:

complexity
Hoffman's index of complexity for each item. This is just $\{(\sum_i a_i^2)^2\}/\{\sum_i a_i^4\}$ where $a_i$ is the factor loading on the $i$th factor. From Hofmann (1978), MBR. See also Pettersson and Turkheimer (2010).

Complexity (com) is reported for every item.  The mean complexity is the average across items.